# Is there a way to query file names in a directory within Access 2010?

Tags: script, batch, microsoft-access, query

Is there a native function for this within Access? Or would I have to do this with a batch script somehow?

Moreover, could I rename the files in a directory based on fields in an Access table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Dir function in VBA help to show you how to loop through a folder looking for files.   Note that you must be in the VBA editor to search VBA help.

See the Name statement which "Renames a disk file, directory, or folder."

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a native function for this within Access? Or would I have to do this with a batch script somehow?

If you add the Microsoft Scripting Runtime as a reference you can use `FileSystemObject` from VBA. See [here](http://www.techbookreport.com/tutorials/fso1.html) for some good examples.

> Moreover, could I rename the files in a directory based on fields in an Access table?

You can do this with VBA.

Comment: Is there some reason you go for an outside library instead of recommending the built-in Dir() function?

Comment: @David W. Fenton - I thought that to rename files you needed `FileSystemObject` but as Tony points out you can use `Name`. So all the functionality is built into VBA.